# Is there an implementation of the Lengauer-Tarjan dominator tree algorithm in the Java-based jgrapht graph library?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, graph-theory, jgrapht

I am looking for a graph library that provides an implementation of the Lengauer-Tarjan dominator tree algorithm [1] in Java (or any other dominator tree algorithm that performs at least equally well).
I stumbled across [jgrapht](https://jgrapht.org/) and I am now curious if this library comes with an algorithm for dominator tree calculation?

If not, do you know of any other graph library (not a single class hosted on GitHub etc.) in Java that supports dominator tree calculation?

Thanks!

[1]
Thomas Lengauer and Robert Endre Tarjan:
A fast algorithm for finding dominators in a flowgraph,
ACM Transactions on Programming Language and Systems, 1(1):121-141, 1979.

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), namely the off-topic list, item 4.

Comment: Currently jgrapht currently does not have such algorithm. We however welcome code submissions :)